# how to rotate an nscell

Tags: cocoa, rotation, nsaffinetransform

I am making a subclass of the NSLevelIndicatorCell and I want to draw it vertically. This doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView{
[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] saveGraphicsState];
NSAffineTransform *transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
[transform rotateByDegrees:90];
[transform concat];
[super drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] restoreGraphicsState];}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “this doesn't work”?

Comment: It is drawing the indicators out of the bounds. Is there a way to turn the whole control and not just draw the cells rotated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[self setBoundsRotation:90];

[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

Now, I just need to figure out how to get the resizable edges to change from horizontal to vertical...